# Add Custom SAPUI5 Library to SAP Cloud Platform Fiori Launchpad (Portal Service)

Tags: sapui5

I've created a custom SAPUI5 library with the SAP Web IDE and deployed the library to the SAP Cloud Platform. The library is used by multiple SAPUI5 applications and works perfect when the apps are launched from the SAP Web IDE. The dependency to the library is defined in the *manifest.json* of each application:

```
"dependencies": {"libs": {"custom.library"}: {}}}
```

Furthermore I've already added the correct path to the file *neo-app.json*.

Now I've registered the SAPUI5 applications to the SAP Cloud Platform Fiori Launchpad. I can start the Launchpad and see the tiles for the apps. But when I start an app the following error occurs: 
Error: failed to load 'custom/library/library.js' from https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.52.17/resources/custom/library/library.js: 404

How can I register the custom UI5 library to the Fiori Launchpad?

Answer (score 0):

On SAP Community, you’ll [find this blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/12/15/sapui5-custom-control-library-web-ide-development-deployment-to-hcp-and-to-on-premise-abap-repository.-part-1) about the SAPUI5 Custom control library.
There it says that you need to add an entry into “routes” array of neo-app.json file for your newly deployed library.
The entry shall look like this:

```
{
       "path": "/webapp/resources/my/custom/control",
       "target": {
             "type": "application",
             "name": "mycustomlib", 
             "entryPath": "/"
       },
       "description": "Custom control library"
}
```

Here, “path” is the path you use in the dependency definition of your controller JS file. 
“name” in “target” clause contains the name under which you deployed the library into SAP Cloud Platform.

Comment: I've already added the path to the neo-app.json. Otherwise the app would not start from SAP Web IDE.

Comment: Have you included “jQuery.sap.registerModulePath” in your component.js as seen [here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3869225) ?

Answer (score 0):

As SAP Fiori Crew pointed out, you need to create a route entry in `neo-app.json` for the SAP Cloud Platform router to know where to serve your library files from when requested by the applications.

A good way to find out the exact URL that needs to be added is checking the Network requests in your browser's Developer Tools, when trying to load the application in the Launchpad:

[image: Failed request to the library-preload.js in a Cloud Fiori Launchpad]

In the example above, adding this entry to `neo-app.json` solved the problem:

```
{
    "path": "/sap/ui5/1/resources/vplanner/common",
    "target": {
        "type": "application",
        "name": "vpfioricommon"
    },
    "description": "Common Library"
}
```